# How to translate and rotate a bitmap on canvas?

Tags: android, matrix, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to draw a bitmap on canvas in the onDraw() method of a view. The bitmap should move and bounce of the edges of the canvas and it should rotate towards the direction of the movement.(like in the image below)
[image: mouse moving around]

I tried the following code. The movement is correct but the bitmap doesn't rotate. I also tried preRotate and setRotate instead of postRotate with the same output. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class AnimatedView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private Context mContext;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    private Handler h;
    private int xVelocity = 15;
    private int yVelocity = 15;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private long FRAME_RATE = 25;
    private int rotation = 0;

    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        h = new Handler();
    }

    private Runnable r = this::invalidate;

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        BitmapDrawable mouse = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mouse0001);
        c.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));

            rotation = (int) ((Math.asin(x / xVelocity)) / (Math.PI / 90));
        if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            rotation = 180 -2 * rotation;
        } else {
            x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;
            if ((x > this.getWidth()) || (x < 0 - mouse.getBitmap().getWidth())) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity * -1;                
                rotation = 180 -2 * rotation;
            }
            if ((y > this.getHeight()) || (y < 0 - mouse.getBitmap().getHeight())) {
                yVelocity = yVelocity * -1;
                rotation = 180 -2 * rotation;
            }
        }

        matrix.postRotate(rotation,  mouse.getBitmap().getWidth()/2,  mouse.getBitmap().getHeight()/2);
        matrix.setTranslate(x, y);
        c.drawBitmap( mouse.getBitmap(), matrix, null);


        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use canvas.roate()**

```
c.rotate(90);   // 90 is degree.
```

Comment: Yes Thanks, That was on of my mistakes.With the correct calculation for the rotation and with c.rotate(degrees, x, y) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my calculation for the rotation was wrong. 
The result of (Math.asin(x / xVelocity) was NaN and so the rotation was always 0.